# Intval() en php

Tags: php, datatables

tengo un trozo de codigo que se usa en Datatables server side , y no se para que sirve esta funcion, ya que esta dentro de la respuesta, mas no en la libreria.

```
$output = array(
    "draw" =>         intval($_POST["draw"]),
    "recordsTotal" => get_all_data($cnn),
    "recordsFiltered" => $number_filter_row,
    "data" =>  $rst

);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es una forma de obtener el valor entero de una variable, y hace la conversion con una base que puede especificarse o tomarse por defecto en cuyo caso es base 10. La variable a convertir puede ser de distintos tipos.

int intval($var [,$base])

Mas info aqui [http://php.net/manual/es/function.intval.php].

Puedes ver ejemplos aqui [https://stackoverflow.com/q/1912599/5675636]